# Conditional Statements to show Open Hours

Tags: conditionals, grid, time

So I want to show "Open-Now" if the current time is in betwee in the open hours (which are put in a grid time select field).

This is what I have right now:

`{if {current_time format="%h"} >= {branch_hours:opening_hour} && {current_time format="%h"} <= {branch_hours:closing_hour} } <span class="open-now text-right">Open Now</span> {/if}</p>`

It's not really working, and not sure why? Is what I'm aiming for even possible?

Comment: Just output those bad boys next to eachother without the if command and report back. What does `{current_time format="%h"} - {branch_hours:opening_hour} - {branch_hours:closing_hour}` output outside of the if statement?

Answer (score 1):

jrothafer's troubleshooting suggestion will tell you a lot. If that looks good, try putting the tags in single quotes like so:

```
{if '{current_time format="%h"}' >= '{branch_hours:opening_hour}' && '{current_time format="%h"}' <= '{branch_hours:closing_hour}' } <span class="open-now text-right">Open Now</span> {/if}
```